# Create New Line in Source

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to dynamically load CSS, JS and other parts and what I'm running into is a little bit of a mess. This doesn't affect functionality as much as I don't like what I see when I view source.
My Source when I view it is as such
[image]

You can see that it's there. It works, but man is that messy!
What I'd like it to do is have a new line between each source, the code that I use to pull this information is

```
function LoadTheme($argument) {
    switch($argument) {
        case "active":
            $theme = Frontend; break;
        default: $theme = $argument; break;
    }
    $configFile = "config.json";
    $configPath = frontend.'/'.$theme.'/'.$configFile;
    $themePath = frontend.'/'.$theme.'/';
    if(file_exists($configPath)) {
        LoadThemeIncludes($configPath,$themePath);
    }
    else {
        echo "Fatal Error. No theme Configuration Found";
    }
}
function LoadThemeIncludes($configPath,$themePath) {
    $string = file_get_contents($configPath);
    $json_a = json_decode($string, true);
    $stylesheets = $themePath.''.$json_a['includes']['css'].'/*.css';
    foreach(glob($stylesheets) as $stylesheet) {
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.ConvertURL($stylesheet).'" media="screen" />';

    }
}
function ConvertURL($path) {
    $cv = str_replace(public_p, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $path);
    return $cv;
}
```

And the config file that I use is a json file formatted as such:

```
{
  "details": {
    "author": "Morgan Green",
    "details": "Revelio Theme",
    "lastUpdate": "6/17/2016"
  },
  "includes": {
    "parts": "parts",
    "script": "jscript",
    "css": "css",
    "fonts": "fonts",
    "images": "images",
    "templates": "templates",
    "functions": "functions.d"
  },
  "options": {
    "layout": "mod_right"
  }
}
```

What I want to accomplish is when a user views the source they don't just see it wrapping like the picture has, but rather
the source would have a new line after each one.

Comment: just add a new line to your echo `echo '<link></link>' . PHP_EOL;`

Comment: Past hour and a half googling and that did it right there.... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print a new line:

```
echo PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can echo out a new-line with `\r\n`.

So you have to alter your for-each-loop inside the function `LoadThemeIncludes`:

```
foreach(glob($stylesheets) as $stylesheet) {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.ConvertURL($stylesheet).'" media="screen" />' . "\r\n";
}
```

Or like mentioned in the other answers you could use the constant `PHP_EOL` for it.

Comment: I think you need to use double quotes for `\r\n` to work